# TensorFlow Keras use BatchNormalization moving statistics during training phase?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, batch-normalization

By default, TensorFlow's Keras' BatchNormalization will train by using the mean and variance of the current batch. At the same time, it will incorporate these values into the moving average statistics. Then, during testing, the moving average statistics will be used rather than the statistics of the test data. This is documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization#call_arguments).

Is there a way to use the moving statistics for the normalization both during training and testing? Specifically, using them while still updating the statistics during training, but not updating the statistics during testing?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to do it? If you take a look at the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf), you will see that the only reason why moving average statistics is used, is the case where you want to perform inference with the number of samples less then the batch size. In any other case, one should compute batch normalization.

Comment: @carobnodrvo, Because I want to test the case where training and validation are using the same statistics. Different applications show small benefits from all manner of variation on which ways to train and test with batch normalization, and the several works have pointed out issues in the original implementation of batch norm.  Notably group norm and batch renorm (though, these are both focused on small batch sizes). However, in my recent (non-small batch) application, batch norm had trouble, but batch renorm did not. This was unexpected. I believe using the average statistics may fix it.